# Wrong result for bitwise operation r << 24, why?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have an enum:

```
public enum STAR_TYPE {
    FAST(255, 255, 255),
    NORMAL(190, 190, 190),
    SLOW(120, 120, 120);

    private int color;

    private STAR_TYPE(int r, int g, int b) {
        int R = r << 24;
        int G = g << 16;
        int B = b << 8;
        color = R | G | B | 0xff;
    }

    public static STAR_TYPE getRandomType() {
        return values()[MathUtils.random(0, values().length - 1)];
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }
}
```

I wanna convert a RGBA value to an integer where the transparency is always 255. I am using bitwise operations for this purpose. But r << 24 doesn't work. It returns wrong results.

For 255 r << 24 should return 4278190080 but it returns -16777216.

For 190 r << 24 should return 3187671040 but it returns -1107296256.

Only for 120 r << 24 returns the correct result of 2013265920.

I found out that the values calcualted are the Decimals from signed 2's complement. Nice to know but I never asked for this. I wanna have the positive value. 
How can I get the desired values? I am confused.

Comment: Why do you think you need a positive value?

Comment: Normally it doesn't matter if the number is positive or negative, as long as the bits are correct. If you still want to have for whatever reason positive values you would have to work with `long`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the fact this is negative as significant.

You are packing four 8-bit values into a 32-bit value:

```
RRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAA
```

If the most-significant bit, the left-most R bit, is set (that is, your R value is at least 128), the corresponding 32-bit int value is negative.

But this doesn't mean anything, really, in terms of the integer value. You are, in a sense, abusing the int data type by using it to store four 8-bit values. It just so happens some of the resulting 32-bit values are also otherwise used to represent negative numbers.

Comment: To "convince" your self that the values are correct, you could print out the hexadecimal representation of the value. That will not have a sign and will show you that the bit pattern is as expected.

Comment: @DanielJunglas or just specify the int value in hex in the first place, e.g. `0xFF_FF_FF_FF`, `0xBE_BE_BE_FF` etc. Not much to be gained by the bit shifting here.

Comment: The thing is I wanna use this as an easy way to set colors. Instead of handling 4 variables it would be just one...one integer value. As I saw this technique in books and tutorials it is a very common way to handle color values. But in my code the color of the objects remain black and I am wondering why? So the code above is correct? The issue must be somewhere else in the code?

Comment: @Peter your "fast" star type should be white, for example. If it's not, the problem is elsewhere.